# Get max/min value of the column independet from where clause

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am having the following query and running it on postgress

```
select 
    p.id as p_id,
    p.name as p_name,
    p.tags,
    p.creator,
    p.value
    p.creation_date,
    cp.id as c_part_id,
    fr.distance
    count(*) OVER() AS total_item
from t_p p 
    left join t_c_part cp on p.id = cp.p_id 
    left join t_fl fr on p.id = fr.p_id  
where p.name = 'test'
ORDER BY p.id ASC, p.name ASC 
OFFSET 0 FETCH NEXT 25 ROWS only
```

**What is missing here is that I also need to get max(p.value) and min(p.value) not affected by the "where" clause - so calculated from total (all) values.**

I am dreaming that I can do it within one query and reduce the number of transactions.
Honestly not sure if it is possible!

What I tried is something like this ->

```
SELECT 
    (SELECT COUNT(*) from t_p) as count, 
    (SELECT json_agg(t.*) FROM (
        SELECT * FROM t_p
        where ***
    ) AS t) AS rows
```

But this one did not look really nice as it require additional JSON  manipulation at the backend.

I discovered that I might try to use the "with" statement to create a temporary view so the where condition is only evaluated once, but did not succeed to make it works...

Comment: You may not be able to up-vote yet, but can and should accept the answer you feel most helpful. This helps future questioners having the same or similar questions and removes the question from the unanswered queue. Please do not leave a successfully answered question as unanswered.

Comment: That's something I personally prefer to do.I did not know that I can mark the answer as the correct one. Let me try

Comment: @Belayer - done thanks for the good tip... I totally forget that I can do this. rarely asking questions only reading)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the extra columns as scalar subqueries in the form `(select min(value) from t_p)`. Their values are not related to the main query so they should be totally independent.

Your original query has some minor syntax issues (missing commas). I fixed those and the result is:

```
select 
    p.id as p_id,
    p.name as p_name,
    p.tags,
    p.creator,
    p.value,
    p.creation_date,
    cp.p_id as c_part_id,
    fr.distance,
    count(*) OVER() AS total_item,
    (select min(value) from t_p) as min_value,
    (select max(value) from t_p) as max_value
from t_p p 
    left join t_c_part cp on p.id = cp.p_id 
    left join t_fl fr on p.id = fr.p_id  
where p.name = 'test'
ORDER BY p.id ASC, p.name ASC 
OFFSET 0 FETCH NEXT 25 ROWS only
```

See running query (without any data) at [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hTcsQsh98FmNCf8K1T83w7/0).

Comment: Many thanks for your advice, when trying this getting some error =>
SQL Error [42803]: ERROR: column "p.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

Comment: @Vartan I fixed some minor syntax issues. See update.

Comment: seems working as a charm - I was having also a syntax mistake...
Thanks a lot going to try more on some examples

Comment: sorry cant vote up - I am noob without reputation)

Comment: @Vartan Glad it was helpful!

Answer (score 0):

You could get the minimum and maximum "on the side" like this:

```
select 
    p.id as p_id,
    p.name as p_name,
    p.tags,
    p.creator,
    p.value
    p.creation_date,
    cp.id as c_part_id,
    fr.distance,
    count(*) OVER() AS total_item,
    p.min_value,
    p.max_value
from (SELECT id,
             name,
             tags,
             creator,
             value,
             creation_date,
             min(value) OVER () AS min_value,
             max(value) OVER () AS max_value,
      FROM t_p) AS p 
    left join t_c_part cp on p.id = cp.p_id 
    left join t_fl fr on p.id = fr.p_id  
where p.name = 'test'
ORDER BY p.id ASC, p.name ASC 
OFFSET 0 FETCH NEXT 25 ROWS only;
```

Comment: Oh interesting. I believe I tried nested query but this will be affected by “where” clause so it will return me max and min only for the given selection. What I am looking is to have general max and min of complete data table

Comment: For example as you can see I am already having window function here count(*) OVER() AS total_item , and this will return total after “where” clause, which is good in this case. But for max and min I would like to get it out of “where” scope

Comment: I have revised the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can join to a sub-query that calculates both MIN & MAX.

```
... 
from t_p p 
    left join t_c_part cp on p.id = cp.p_id 
    left join t_fl fr on p.id = fr.p_id 
    cross join (
      select 
        min(value) as min_value
      , max(value) as max_value 
      , avg(value) as avg_value
      from t_p
    ) as v
...
```

Then use `v.min_value` and `v.max_value` in the select.
Doesn't even have to be a LATERAL.

Comment: Thanks for the help, however, seems adding sub query somehow ignored

p_id|p_name|tags|creator|cp_part_id|fl_part_id|total_count|
----+--------+----+-------+-----------+---------+-----------+
   1|    test   | test|           |               |             |             1|

Sorry for bad formating - no chance to keep it same like in db manager output